# How to install package from source as system package?

Tags: ros, colcon

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to set up a docker image which includes some custom source built ROS packages.  Of course, the user of this image should not need to care where these custom ROS packages were built, and should be able to use them by simply running `source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash`, i.e. they behave no different from system packages installed with `apt install ros-foxy-...`.  How should I run my build command (`colcon build`) such that these custom built packages get installed in a path that can be found by sourcing `/opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash`?

I've read [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/295462/how-to-properly-install-packages-from-source/), however, that requires user to source multiple workspaces which is not ideal.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371820/how-to-install-package-from-source-as-system-package?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2021-02-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

If you run `colcon build -h` you will see all the available options. In this case you should use:

```
  --install-base INSTALL_BASE
                    The base path for all install prefixes (default:
                    install)
```

Your command should look like: `colcon build --install-base /opt/ros/foxy/ ...`

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.ros.org/users/50386/ahcorde/) with karma: 421 on 2021-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-15**:
And of course run `colcon` with the required permissions once it gets to the `install` step.

In a Docker build that'll probably not be a problem, as you typically run everything as `root` there, but for regular use this is important, as otherwise CMake/Python/`whatever_builds_the_pkgs` will not be able to copy files to the `/opt/ros` prefix.

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2021-02-15**:
Seems `--merge-install` is also required or else `/opt/ros/foxy` will be littered with package directories instead of them being placed nicely in the existing `lib`, `include`, `share` directories